# Using Media Player classic as default video viewer for all users

Tags: file-association, windows-server-2012-r2, default-settings, multiple-users, terminal-server

I have set up a number of terminal servers and and we have media player classic installed as some users need to view video files.

I (administrator) have set mpc-hc64.exe as my default video player and it works great, however I'm struggling to have this set as the default video player for all users.

Logging in as one of the end users and opening a video results in windows media player trying to configure itself.

Is there a way I can force this association via the registry, or some other way?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 :)

Comment: Edit your question